# Bootstap datatable ajax reload when new data appear

Tags: python, django, ajax, datatables

I'm showing data in table using django view, in addition I've bootstrap datatable that is responsible for pagination, searching and sorting functionalities. The problem is when I'm adding the data to the database (using ajax call) the pagination is not working and number of records is not refreshed.

view.py

```
def patients_list(request):
    patients = Patient.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'patients/patients.html', {'patients': patients})
```

ajax call for inserting data

```
  var loadForm = function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: btn.attr("data-url"),
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#modal-book .modal-content").html("");
        $("#modal-book").modal("show");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });
  };
```

datatable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#book-table').DataTable({
      retrieve: true,
      "order": [],
      "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets"  : 'no-sort',
        "orderable": false,
    }]
});
});
```

Does anyone knows how can I refresh the datatable so that number of rows will align with newly added ones? 
What I've tried already was `ajax.reload()` and `ajax.draw()`, but nothing worked.

Comment: Just for my understanding: You put something like this: `$('#book-table').DataTable().ajax().reload();` into the btn ajax success function - and it did not trigger a data fetch and table re-draw - is that correct? And the success function is definitely firing, e.g. you can see it in the debugger, or add an `alert("it fired!);` or something like that?

Comment: How are you populating your DataTable? You can only use the ajax option to reload it if you used ajax to populate it in the first place, and I don't see an ajax option in your table definition.

Comment: @andrewjames exactly as you are saying

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming. My comments are not relevant; but @mark_b's comments absolutely are (mixing ajax and non-ajax).